# ASP MVC 3 - Ajax.BeginForm not submitting model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 partials on my main view, each uses an Ajax form with unobtrusive javascript enabled.

The first partial works fine and will submit its model to the controller and everyone is happy. However the 2nd partial never sends over a model to the controller when submitting.

They both are strongly typed partial views, and both use Ajax.BeginForm.

One thing that is different is that the 2nd partial takes a model that contains a list i.e:

```
// View Model
public class SecondModel
{
    public IList<SomeModel> MyList {get; set;}
}

// Partial View
@model SecondModel

@for(var i=0;i<Model.MyList.Count;i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyList[i].SomeField)
}
```

The second model is displayed fine on the view, but when I go to submit, the controller has an empty model when debugging.

I have tried making the variable *i* also assign to a local var currentIndex = i; or something similar incase the lambdas were not correctly receiving i.

Looking online has yielded nothing, so im a bit baffled as to why one works and the other doesnt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out for some unknown reason, the autobinder doesn't work... but UpdateModel(myModel); in the controller does work... so using that.